# How to use stack navigation in side drawer navigation with header in react navigation v6

Tags: react-native

i am using the React navigation version 6 and i want to header of navigation
with drawer and Stack
but when i use stack in drawer navigation then shows to two header
the below is code which i write

```
const StockStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

 const StockScreen = ({ navigation }) => (
  <StockStack.Navigator>
    <StockStack.Screen name="StockList" component={StockList} />
    <StockStack.Screen name="StockItemDetail" component={StockItemDetail}/>
   </StockStack.Navigator>
)
```

and this the drawer navigation

```
  return (
    
    <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={ props => <SideMenu {...props}  /> }>
     <Drawer.Screen name="StockScreenList" component={StockScreen} />  
     </Drawer.Navigator>

       );
```

any can help you can i remove the drawer header

[image]

Comment: screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}